# HTML form and other elements

Tags: html, behavior

I am new to HTML and still trying to understand some concepts. Here it is one that I do not understand at all. After trying HTML form I noticed that if I have a form with attribute name I can access that form the following way document.*attribute_name* or document[*attribute_name*]. However if I try to do the same on a div for instance, it does not work. Can somebody please explain me why is this so.
Also, I was wondering if it good practice to use a form when using AJAX. Let say that I have some fields  inside a form but I am using ajax and the form never is "posted" as I am using AJAX to change field's contents.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Creaven Thanks! But I guess I did not explain myself well enough. I am not talking about the elements in the form, but the form itself. Let's say I have a form with the name attribute set to 'userinfo', that is <form name='userinfo'></form>, then I can access the form in the following way document.userinfo. However, if I try to do the same with a div element, this does not work. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a form has the name attribute in order for you to be able to pass a value to a PHP/ AJAX script.

When writing THE FORM :

```
<FORM action = 'addDetailsToDatabase.php' method = 'post' >
<input name ='myName'>
<button type = 'submit'>
</form>
```

When you submit this form it will post the input field value that has the name attribute 'myName' to the addDetailsToDatabase.php script. So now whatever has been entered and submitted in the input you can use in your PHP script.

TAGS do not generally have a need for a name attribute. (I am saying generally need just incase theiris some library out there that uses this I have never seen a name attribut on a div tag.

The best way to get a div is to get it by ID . document.getElementByID('yourdivid') - Javascript.

Your div will look like this

You can use AJAX to post a form to be be run by a PHP script and this has the added benefit of the whole page not being refreshed.

Anwsering the second part its hard what you are asking. With Ajax you can make your page as dynamic as you want

You can select from the database and echo wherever you want the options are limitless (almost). The best thing to do is to learn HTML = SIMPLE Learn CSS =SIMPLE. Then learn some simple JQUERY or javascript. If your dealing with forms and databases learn how to post a form to PHP script and store in a database and then retrieve using the select statement (prepared statements will set you up for years to come try and avoid old SQL tutorials)

Once you get this learn your AJAX to fill the gaps